# How to change a parameter group value back to its default value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In a paramater group in RDS on Amazon Web Services I changed the wait_timeout and interactive_timeout values in the parameter group to 28800 which supposedly is the default value trying to solve a problem I had.

However before I changed it that value was just empty, there was no value there.

Now I am trying to update it back to no value there as I am seeing much higher costs in Amazon Relational Database Service which I assume is somehow related to that. I tried to remove that value I added from there and save, but I get:

Error saving: invalid parameter value: (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: c4abcb8b-3d1c-48c3-9ef6-62d3d6dd0ac8; Proxy: null)

Does anybody know how I can reset it to having no value there?

There is a reset button at the top, but I am not sure if that means it will reset the whole parameter group or just the selected values?

Comment: How would timeout settings affect your bill?

Comment: @jordanm not sure I have the timeout settings added there because a service seemed to be creating a lot of sleeping connections. Not sure if taking care of those things increases the price of the relational database service, but it seemed to be spiking in the last few days for some reason. Not sure if its related to that or just some coincidence, but it spiked by quite a bit so not sure what else it could be. I don't have much knowdlege of how their services work. I did this for a friend so, don't want his bill to double or something.

Comment: Just create parameter group to default one. Default one is always constant, and you can't change anything.

Comment: @Marcin yeah but I dont know if other values were different in the ones where I changed stuff, so...I can't just create a default one. The question is, why can't I change it back to having no value there.

Comment: Can you update with screenshots from your current account?